# How to update an integer in grafbase

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql, mutation

I am trying to update an int in grafbase but it returns me Expected an Object for. Although when i created eveything works fine in the update i get this error.

```
export const updatePetMutation = `
mutation UpdatePet($id: ID!, $input: PetUpdateInput!) {
    petUpdate(by: { id: $id }, input: $input) {
        pet {
            name
            id
    
        createdBy {
         email
         name

         }
        }
    }
}
```

`;

Answer (score 0):

Here's everything you need https://grafbase.com/docs/database/mutations.

Instead of input :`{yourfield:yourint}` you need to have: `{yourfield:{set:yourint}}`